# Memory management in Swift: memory don't released after NSOperation ends

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, macos, cocoa

Could someone please clarify one thing about Swift's memory management?

I have following app delegate:

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    private let _queue = NSOperationQueue()

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

        _queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1

        _queue.addOperation(Operation())
        _queue.addOperation(Operation())
        _queue.addOperation(Operation())
    }
}

private class Operation: NSOperation {

    override func main() {

        autoreleasepool {

            var d = [String: AnyObject]()

            for i in 1...1000 {
                d[i.description] = Repeat(count: 10000, repeatedValue: "ABCDEF").joinWithSeparator("") // tested with repeat or just large string
            }

            d.removeAll()
        }
    }
}
```

After application started, I enqueue three synchronous operations. Each operation just creates very large dictionary (struct) with very large strings (also structs).

Since all created data is value type and nothing was captured, I believe that **memory should be released** when main function ends. In fact, I added `d.RemoveAll()` just in case to be sure that memory released.

After all operations completed Activity Monitor shows following information:
[image]

My application still occupy *26.7mb* but if i remove all `_queue.addOperation(Operation())` it would be about *7mb*. Why additional 19mb of memory wasn't released when all operations completed?

@Lou Franco
I changed app delegate to this

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {  
    for _ in 1...100 {
        _queue.addOperation(Operation())
    }
}
```

And now 8 operations run simultaneously. After all operations completed about 40mb left unreclaimed. I tried to queue *100000 operations*. App din't crash for 40 minutes. It's memory usage was *600...1000mb*, but I wasn't able to wait until all operations completed.

Comment: I would check this with the leaks instrument to be sure.  I don't know if Memory in this context is allocated to objects or just reserved pages (which might get reclaimed later)

Comment: No leaks found by instruments. And memory heap profiling states what only 9mb left persistent instead of 25mb shown by instruments. As I understand Memory - is what can be reclaimed when system doesn't have enough memory and Private Memory is what application actually uses.. But I don't know for sure and can't find where I can read more specific.

Comment: I would believe the leaks instrument that you don't have leaks.  Activity monitor doesn't know about that -- it's counting what has been reserved for your process -- you can't directly control that.  Better to use the Debug Navigator in Xcode for a quick look at memory usage in the app.

Comment: I checked the Debug Navigator and it shows same amount of memory like 'Memory' tab in Activity monitor. I am wondering is this memory behaviour could be improved..And why this is happening in first place

Comment: I think this is not a problem -- run many many more operations -- does the memory go up indefinitely and you eventually crash or do the memory pages get reused (shown by the memory leveling off at some point)

Comment: @LouFranco I've tested case with many operations run simultaneously. App didn't crashed and it's memory hold at some level but it's seams like some small amount of memory still won't be released.

Comment: You also may ensure, that the operations get _deinitialised_. I'm confident they do - but just in case.  By the way, you can easily implement this use case with a dispatch queue and closures - except that you cannot (conveniently) set the max concurrent operations on that queue other than 1 or greater than 1.

Comment: @MaximKosov From what you have said, there is no leak or problem -- this is normal. If the OS needs that memory, it will reclaim it.  If you were leaking, you'd eventually crash and Instruments would show it.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't leaking. The process doesn't immediately yield all memory back to the operating system - that would be very wasteful and expensive. The memory is returned to the `malloc` free memory list.

Running your test code I actually see memory climb then drop after each operation completes.

I also suspect that memory is not returned to the OS in cases where it is fragmented (some objects are still alive in-between lots of free bytes). This variant of your example hits a high-water mark of several hundred MB then drops back to 13.8 when the operations complete. By allocating contiguous buffers we know there will be plenty of big chunks ready to be returned to the OS.

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    private let _queue = NSOperationQueue()

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

        _queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1

        _queue.addOperation(Operation())
        _queue.addOperation(Operation())
        _queue.addOperation(Operation())
    }
}

private class Operation: NSOperation {

    override func main() {
        autoreleasepool {
            let count = 100000000
            let p = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.alloc(count)
            for i in 0..<count {
                p.advancedBy(i).initialize(i)
            }
            p.destroy(count)
            p.dealloc(count)
        }
    }
}
```